# Check if the page is a node using arguments in D7

Tags: nodes

In Drupal 6, to check if current page is a node, we use the following snippet:

```
if (arg(0)=='node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) { /* Do stuff. */ }
```

Since this is a frequently used statement, I wonder if there's a shorter way to do this in Drupal 7, such as something similar to the following:

```
if (is_node()) { /* Do stuff. */ }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually, there is a function that is available in Drupal 6 too: [`menu_get_object()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7). With the default values, it will return a node object if the URL for the current page starts with *node/[node ID]* (where *[node ID]* is the node ID), and `FALSE` in the other cases; the function is particularly useful if, after verifying the current page is a node page, you also need to access the node object associated with the page, and the function that is calling `menu_get_object()` doesn't get a node object between its arguments.

In Drupal 7, there is also another function, but its purpose is just to verify if the current viewed page is the full page view of the node passed as argument: [`node_is_page()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_is_page/7).

Comment: That's not strictly true, though, right? If you call `menu_get_object` on a taxonomy listing page, or a view, it will still return an object, but that object will not be a node. I think maybe `arg(0) === 'node'` works instead?

Comment: No, `menu_get_object()` returns an object only when the user is viewing a node page, since its first parameter has the default value of `'node'`, otherwise it returns `FALSE`. With `arg(0) == 'node'` you cannot know if the user is editing a node.